# ¿Porque a pesar de ejecutarse el código correctamente el resultado es distinto al esperado?

Tags: c++, archivo, csv

Estoy diseñando un menu en el que una de las opciones es buscar un usuario y sus iteraciones en una fichero externo cuya direccion esta guardada en direccion y se enlaza con el correctamente pero tras la ejecucion de este codigo que incluye invocante e invocado:

```
else if (eleccion == "usuario"){
        string idnum;
        cout << "\nIntroduzca el ID del usuario:";
        cin >> idnum;
        int viajes;
        viajes = usuarioFun(idnum, direccion);
        cout << "\nEl/la usuario/a " << idnum << " ha realidado " << viajes << " viajes.\n";
    }


int usuarioFun(string idnum, char* direccion){

    ifstream f;
    f.open (direccion);
    if (f.is_open()){

        int viajes = 0;
        string id;
        string retiro;
        string estacionRet;
        string anclaje;
        string estacionAnc;             

        while (!f.eof()){

            getline (f, id, ',');   
            getline (f, retiro, ',');
            getline (f, estacionRet, ',');
            getline (f, anclaje, ',');
            getline (f, estacionAnc, 'n');

            if (id == idnum){
                viajes++;
            }
        }
        f.close();
        return viajes;
    }
    else{
        cout << "\nSe ha producido un error, intentelo de nuevo por favor\n";
    }

}
```

Lo que acabo obteniendo es que el resultado de viajes sigue siendo 0 y no veo el error. Aun asi, me parece que hacer `getline` de cada dato del fichero (.csv) es un costo extra que se podria reducir al solo coger el primer valor que es con el que se trabaja pero tambien estoy inseguro de como hacerlo propiamente.
¿Alguna idea de porque pasa o de como mejorarlo?

Para mas informacion, este es una imagen de una parte del archivo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y aqui esta el resultado obtenido desde la consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ademas al final tengo un input de una instruccion que no parece existir ya que no es pedida al usuario pero eso es un error menor que no tiene mucha importancia. Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí

```
getline (f, estacionAnc, 'n');
```

si no es un error de *copy/paste*, te falta la barra. Debería ser

```
getline (f, estacionAnc, '\n');
```

Por otra parte, no compruebas errores, y usas bastantes mas variables e instrucciones de las necesarias: si el `IDUsuario` está al principio de la línea ... ¿ para que quieres mas ?

```
int usuarioFun( const string &idnum, char* direccion ) {
  ifstream f;
  f.open( direccion );

  if( !f.is_open( ) ) {
    cout << "\nSe ha producido un error, intentelo de nuevo por favor\n";
    return 0;
  }

  int viajes = 0;
  string line;

  while( true ) {
    getline( f, line );   

    if( !f ) break;

    if( !strncmp( line.c_str( ), idnum.c_str( ), idnum.length( ) ) ++viajes;
  }

  f.close( );

  return viajes;
}
```

De todas formas, las líneas se siguen leyendo completas. Es imposible no hacerlo así, salvo que sean de longitud fija todas ellas, o puedas obtener su longitud de alguna forma. ¿ Como sabremos donde termina una y empieza otra ?